# MAX and SUM query from same table

Tags: oracle, sum, max

I have a table similar the below:

```
 part | location  | qty
    1 | Seattle   |  2
    2 | New York  |  3
    2 | New York  |  2
    1 | Seattle   |  1
    1 | New York  |  1
    1 | Warehouse |  5
```

Which means part I have 3 part ones in Seattle, and one in New York(ignore warehouse at this point). If I had a location, let's say in Dallas that needs stock of part 1, I want Seattle to send it since they have more than New York.

```
SELECT part
      ,SUM(QTY_AVAILABLE) AS QTY_AVAILABLE
      ,LOCATION
FROM table1
WHERE LOCATION IN ('Warehouse','New York','Seattle','Dallas')
GROUP BY PN, LOCATION
```

The above gives me how many items are in stock at each location. I want to show only the location from above list that has the most items in stock for each part.

The second portion of my question, how could I show the locations to transfer the part from and ignore the fact the warehouse has the part, unless no location but the warehouse has that part? If New York ran out of part 2, but the warehouse has it, then the query should say the part needs to come from the warehouse.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are the parts shipped one at a time (quantity of 1)? What if you need quantity of 4, the warehouse has 10, but New York has 2, Dallas has 1 and Seattle has 1 - should all four be shipped from the warehouse, or should they be shipped from New York, Dallas and Seattle? Your description suggests it should be from NY, Dallas and Seattle, but is that indeed the desired answer?

Comment: The main purpose is to get stores that don't use a product to ship it to somewhere that does use it. Another part of the query joins who has an item but hasn't used it in a year. If location 1 needs 4, they'll eventually get 4, but I still want location 2 to send their qty of 1 since it's just collecting dust.

Comment: OK, then the solution I posted yesterday may be what you need. That was the assumption I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work - all in one query. Notice the additional examples in the "test data" (I added parts 3 and 4, each with a different situation). I didn't filter so the only locations are New York, Seattle and Dallas; that is easy to do if needed.

```
with
     test_data ( part, location, qty ) as (
       select 1, 'Seattle'  , 2 from dual union all
       select 2, 'New York' , 3 from dual union all
       select 2, 'New York' , 2 from dual union all
       select 1, 'Seattle'  , 1 from dual union all
       select 1, 'New York' , 1 from dual union all
       select 1, 'Warehouse', 5 from dual union all
       select 3, 'Dallas'   , 2 from dual union all
       select 3, 'Warehouse', 4 from dual union all
       select 4, 'Warehouse', 3 from dual
     )
--  End of test data (not part of the solution). Query begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select   part, location, sum_qty
from     (
           select   part, location, sum(qty) as sum_qty,
                    row_number() over ( partition by part 
                                        order by case when location != 'Warehouse' 
                                                      then 0 end,
                                                 sum(qty) desc
                                      ) as rn
           from     test_data
           group by part, location
         )
where    rn = 1
order by part
;

 PART LOCATION     SUM_QTY
----- --------- ----------
    1 Seattle            3
    2 New York           5
    3 Dallas             2
    4 Warehouse          3
```

Comment: This is effectively what I was going to type out, too. Good one, @mathguy.

Comment: It looks like this is doing it, but it's now joining incorrectly on another subquery so I can't be 100% sure. It looks like I just need to switch a few things around, but it does exactly what I want it to. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

First use rank function to select TOP one for given part like this:

```
  select part, location from ( 
  select 
      row_number() over (order by sum(qty) desc) rn,
      part,
--      sum(qty) as qty_available,
      location
  from test
    where location in ('Warehouse','New York','Seattle','Dallas')
    group by part, location
    ) where rn = 1;
--    group by part, location
```

Secondly using filter for locations with non-zero stocks and simulating selection of location having part 1 once New-York ran out of stock.

```
select part, location from ( 
  select 
      row_number() over (partition by part order by sum(qty) desc) rn,
      part,
      sum(qty) as qty_available,
      location
  from test
    where location in ('Warehouse',
    -- 'New York', -- New York ran out of the parts
    'Seattle','Dallas')
    group by part, location
    ) where rn = 1
    and part = 1
    and qty_available > 1;
```

I hope this will be any good.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following also works:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM inventory i
INNER JOIN (SELECT i2.part_no, MAX(i2.stock) AS STOCK
            FROM inventory i2
            WHERE i2.location <> 'Warehouse'
            GROUP BY i2.part_no) sub ON i.part_no = sub.part_no AND i.stock = sub.stock
WHERE i.location <> 'Warehouse'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM inventory i
WHERE i.location = 'Warehouse'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x'
                FROM inventory i2
                WHERE i2.part_no = i.part_no
                AND i2.location <> 'Warehouse');
```

For the first part of you question, you can just use the top half and remove the stuff about location <> 'Warehouse'